# Magento not saving variables or custom blocks in CMS page

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I'm trying to add

```
{{block type=”core/template” template=”page/home.phtml”}}
```

Into a CMS page but it's not saving the code when I go back into the page the code has gone, it also happens when picking a defualt variable

Any help?

Actually if it's any help, it's something to do with my local install - seems to be fine on live. - Strange

Comment: Maybe just a posting error, but does the code contain normal quotes?

Comment: good thinking, but nah just double checked that, also the default var are not saving - I just tried those for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what all that was about!

I deleted the CMS page and recreated it, all is good now... Strange!

Answer (score 0):

You were probably forgetting a closing bracket or something.

Magento will delete your entire line if it's missing a '<' '>' '}' '{'